# Controlling the access of method

Tags: java

Is there a way to write a Web program when you would deliberately specify which classes are allowed to invoke  this or that method? I am writing Web app in Java and using Spring Web MVC. If it is possible please tell me about the methods or technologies being used for that.
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be a design decision if your are building a framework of some kind, so use what language gives you, like access modifiers (private, public and such...).

Even restricting access like this, you can still have code call your methods using reflection, so there is no safe-guard if that's what you want (but "safeguarding" anything like this makes no sense anyway, so... )

Can you describe what are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: I have public method which inserts data into DB table. It is accessed from another package. I want to allow to insert new data only from the chosen class. I know myself only access modifiers. It makes me think that this is nonplus. What about code obfuscation?

Comment: You can always have some kind of security policy implemented if you know what you are doing (like authorization), from your comments and your question it seems you have a flawed design, but I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look up http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html documentation.

Comment: Oh, good, please give me some links to these sort of security solutions. Any suggestion are welcome, more details please. I am learning and programming at the same time. Yes, my design is weak, but I want to know more about it.